# How to connect to an oracle database using databricks

Tags: jdbc, odbc, databricks

I'm trying to connect to oracle database using pyspark in databricks notebook. I can not find any documentation to install the library for the driver on the cluster

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an interactive cluster I'd use maven for the installation. You can specify the Coordinates or search the package you want to install using the UI